# Как задать скругление только с нижней стороны?

Tags: html, css

Есть эллипс
А можно задать скругление только с нижней стороны?
Сейчас задается и с вверху, и с низу.

пример - clip-path: ellipse(90% 45%);

Comment: `clip-path: ellipse(90% 100% at 50% 0);`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.circle {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: violet;
  clip-path: circle(61.0% at 51% 12%);
}

.ellipse {
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  background-color: aqua;
  clip-path: ellipse(90% 50% at 50% 28%)
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="ellipse"></div>
```

Вот так это можно реализовать при помощи `clip-path`. Вариант с кругом и вариант с эллипсом